# Taking derivatives of a vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors, partial-derivative

I stumbled across the following question in a machine learning textbook:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $y = $sin$(Ax) \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. What is $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}?$ What is its dimension?

So my initial approach to this question was the following. If $x$ is an n-dimensional vector, then $x$ has the following form $<x_{1}, x_{2}.....x_{n}>$. Now since, sin$(Ax)$ is an m-dimensional vector, it must be the case that A is an m X n matrix. But after this how do I proceed? How are we taking the derivative of this vector? And what is the dimension for this? If someone has a concrete example they could present, that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: How do you define the $\sin$ of a vector?

Comment: @ Mixhael Hoppe: Just out of curiosity, I was wondering if it matters how we define the sin(Ax) for this question. Because it says y has m dimension and the question is how to define the derivative of vector with respect to vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the dimension of x and y, the dimension of the derivative you are looking for is $ m \times n $. This derivative (of vector with respect to vector) is called Jacobian Matrix, J, where:

$$ J_{ij} = \frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}} $$

Example: two input $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ and the outputs are $y_{1} = {x_{1}}{x_{2}}$ and $y_{2} = {x_{1}} - {x_{2}}$.

$$ J = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
 x_{2} &   x_{1}\\
 1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

Further explanation can be found here:

[short intro on vector-to-vector derivatives](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Ecsip/tirgul3_derivatives.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwio_bzZ8dnuAhURvZ4KHbMBAlIQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw3FagyQW0-G-EI9BfiUMJIv)

[The Matrix Calculus You Need For Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01528.pdf)